# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) angular2

Tags: angular

I am getting error while index page loading in angular2.

**Getting error**
1.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
2.Error: XHR error (500 Internal Server Error) loading http://localhost:12228/app/main(…)

Here below my index page code is
Please suggest me how to resolve this error.

Thank you.

```html
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>System.register("angular2/platform/browser");</script>
    <title>Login</title>
  
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.8/angular2.dev.js"></script>
     
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/http.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/router.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
            },
            map: {  // in lieu of index.html script src reference because where using systemjs not commonjs module loader
                app: 'assets/js/app'
            }
        });
        System.import('/app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));



    </script>
</head>
<!-- Run the application -->
<body>
    <h1>Angular 2 Form builder </h1>
    <Login>Loading Sample...</Login>

 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Which HTTP server do you use?

Comment: i am using iis server.http://localhost:12228/index.html

Comment: Do you have an associated error message?

Comment: errors 
.
angular2-polyfills.js:1152 DEPRECATION WARNING: 'enqueueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use addTask/addRepeatingTask/addMicroTask
angular2-polyfills.js:1152 DEPRECATION WARNING: 'dequeueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use removeTask/removeRepeatingTask/removeMicroTask
http://localhost:12228/app/main Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Error: XHR error (500 Internal Server Error) loading http://localhost:12228/app/main(…)

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that SystemJS tries to load `http://localhost1228/app/main` because with you configuration, it should load `http://localhost1228/assets/js/app/main.js` instead.

Perhaps you coulds try this:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    app: 'assets/js/app'
  },
  packages: {
    app: {
      defaultExtension: 'js',
      format: 'register'
    }
  }
});
```